# Convert Class Component to stateless component with React-Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am having difficulty changing the below code to incorporate react-hooks.

I have tried following multiple tutorials as well as reading posts on stack overflow.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isFlipped: false
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(prevState => ({ isFlipped: !prevState.isFlipped }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactCardFlip isFlipped={this.state.isFlipped} flipDirection="horizontal">
        <BusinessCard key="front">
          This is the front of the card.
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click to flip</button>
        </BusinessCard>

        <BusinessCardBack key="back">
          This is the back of the card.
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click to flip</button>
        </BusinessCardBack>
      </ReactCardFlip>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I would like for this to be converted to incorporate React-Hooks

Comment: Check this - https://medium.com/@olinations/10-steps-to-convert-a-react-class-component-to-a-functional-component-with-hooks-ab198e0fa139

Answer (score 3):

To covert the React Component Class to React Component Function, you will have to do

```js
function App() {
  const [isFlipped, setFlipped] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setFlipped(prevState => ({ isFlipped: !prevState.isFlipped }));
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ReactCardFlip isFlipped={isFlipped} flipDirection="horizontal">
        <BusinessCard key="front">
          This is the front of the card.
          <button onClick={handleClick}>Click to flip</button>
        </BusinessCard>
        <BusinessCardBack key="back">
          This is the back of the card.
          <button onClick={handleClick}>Click to flip</button>
        </BusinessCardBack>
      </ReactCardFlip>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Updates:

- preventDefault won't be required
- We should use callback pattern inside setState while updating `new state` which value is dependent on `previous state`